# Initial conditions in odeint or solve_ivp

Tags: matplotlib, odeint

I am new to matplotlib/python. I'd like to solve some simple odes with odeint or solve_ivp in some interval, say for example the segment[0, 10], in which the "initial condition" is at t_0= 5 and not t_0 = 0. It seems to me that both odeint and solve_ivp take, as value y_0, the initial condition, that is, y_0 is the value of the function at the beginning of the specified time array t.

How can i solve an ode, with a condition in the middle of my interval of integration?

Answer (score 0):

#### Let's say you have the following ODE: a body in the earth's gravitational field

```python
 ''' x = distance from the sea level in meters
     R = the radius of earth in meters
     g = the gravitational constant at seal level in meters/seconds^2
     v = velocity in meters/s
 '''
```

v * dv / dx = -g * R^2 / (R + x)^2

#### A ball is tossed from a building that is 30 m high at a velocity of 20 m/s. *The non-zero boundary condition is therefore:*

v( 30 ) = 20

#### To plot this solution, shift the values in the x coordinates so that it starts at 30 meters, the height of the building. Not 0 meters, which represents the ground.

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model(v, x): 

    #constants
    g = 9.80665 #gravitational force at sea level
    R = 6.371e6 #radius of earth

    gamma = - g*(R/(R+x))**2

    dvdx = 1/v*gamma
    return dvdx

#Boundary conditions
v_30 = 20 # Velocity is 20 m/s at x = 30m 

#time points
x =  np.linspace(30, 55) # Start at 30 and not 0 

#solve ODE
v_x =  odeint(model, v_30, x)

#plot results
plt.plot(x, v_x)
```